# Index information from many workbooks against a unique ID

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of unique ID's in a spreadsheet and each (but not all) of the IDs has a single related spreadsheet, all stored in the same location. I need to extract a number from each xlsx. file (in the same cell in each file) and match it to the list of unique IDs. All the files have the same naming convention of 'UniqueID_Otherinformation.xlxs' All unique IDs are 6 figures.

```
Sub OpenFile()
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim sFil As String
    Dim strName As String
    Dim twbk As Workbook
    Dim owbk As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set twbk = ActiveWorkbook
    sPath = "C:\Data Folder\" 
    sFil = Dir(sPath & "*.xls")

    Do While sFil <> ""
        strName = sPath & sFil
        Set owbk = Workbooks.Open(strName)
        Set ws = owbk.Sheets(1)
        ws.Range("A1", Range("A" & Row.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy
        twbk.Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        owbk.Close False 
        sFil = Dir
    Loop

twbk.Save
End Sub
```

I made a start but got very lost very quickly.

Edit: Apologies, not clear about my needs. I'm not sure how to solve the problem. I made a start with code above but it is not very close to what I am intending so am hoping for your expertise here as I am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Your description doesn't tell us what the actual problem is? Is it that you cannot figure out how to complete the task? or is the code throwing an error? please be more specific regarding your issue

Comment: @Zac Apologies, I can't figure out how to complete the task. The code I put in my request is where I have got to in my process but I am now stuck.

Answer (score 0):

`Worksheets("Source").Columns("A:D").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Target").Range("a1")`

Have a look at the above. This code moves from the first sheet to the second. No need to copy+paste, and much simpler method

Apply it to your code as needed